# GET request data - assign to interface/variable

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, request

On my front-end I am displaying employees positions within a company, it calls this variable -

```
setProperties(json: IEngagementUser, engagementType: EngagementType, color: string) {  
this.title = json.position.positionTitle;
```

This works, but i now have been given a new 'endpoint' to get data from and use for the positions, below is the current endpoint being used.

```
  orginazation(sfid: string): Observable<IBaseEngagement> {
const url = `${this.baseURL}/${ENDPOINTS.organizations}/${sfid}`;
return this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json() as IBaseEngagement);
```

}

Now what I'm trying to understand is, If i call this new endpoint i've been given, how do I assign the data from it to an interface or variable to then be assigned to 'this.title'

for more context.. the interface which is being used currently is:

```
   export interface IEngagementUser extends IBaseEngagement {
  startDate?: string;
  endDate?: string;
  status?: string;
  statusLabel?: string;
  account?: IEngagementUserAccount;
  position?: IEngagementUserPosition;
  primaryPosition?: string;
  badgeType?: string;
  engagementRole?: string;
}

export interface IEngagementUserPosition {
  id: string;
  organizationId: string;
  organizationName: string;
  positionTitle: string;
  positionLevel: string;   <----- here!
  isPrimary: boolean;
  startDate: string;
  endDate: string;
}
```

Sorry I know this is a tad messy, i'm new to this. I dont understand how the interface contains the data currently, or how I can GET on the endpoint, assign the data to something and then use it as the this.title currently is, i tried creating a new interface etc but didnt work. I tested the new endpoint on postman and it worked.

Thanks for your time.

Kind regards,

sparlarva

Comment: Can you clarify this?  The current endpoint is returning an `IEngagementUser` (or `IBaseEngagement`), which previously contained the `positionTitle`, but now you want to retrieve the `positionTitle` from a new endpoint while continuing to retrieve the rest of the fields from the original endpoint?

Comment: Yes It must be returning the data to those interfaces as I am taking the data from their currently and displaying the position and the new endpoint could replace the IEngagementUserPosition as it has all the same parts. with an added field for account which has an ID and a fullname

Comment: OK... Looks like this will require some fiddling with Observables, which I'm not familiar with, but hopefully we've collected the necessary information so that someone else will be able to help.